How to use .aar file in React Native application?
I've compiled a Go program into an .aar file to be used in Android project, but doesn't know what to do next.
How to "include" this file and use in .tsx files?
I've used this guide, provided by Expo framework:
https://docs.expo.dev/modules/third-party-library/
it seems to be errors when compile with Native Modules:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Project with path ':expo-modules-core' could not be found in root project 'android'.

